# How to stub promise.all in sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, sinon

I have a function which has 2 APi calls. Iam destructuring the response and sending each response to different functions to perform some operation. I need to write test case to make API call., fetch response & pass it to respective functions.

This is my code

```js
async _fetchComponentDetails() {
    const [firstResponse, secondResponse] = await Promise.all([
      this._getfirstApiResponse(param1, param2),
      this._getSecondApiResponse(param1, param2),
    ]);
    this.formatFirstApiResult = await componentSerives.formatFirstResponseData(firstResponse);
    this.formatSecondApiResult = await componentSerives.formatSecondResponseData(secondResponse);
}
```

This is my Service call

```js
async _getfirstApiResponse(param1, param2) {
    const url = 'api/firstApi';
    const firstResponse = await componentSerives.fetchApiDetails(url, param1, param2);
    return firstResponse;
  }

async _getSecondApiResponse(param1, param2) {
    const url = 'api/secondApi';
    const secondResponse = await componentSerives.fetchApiDetails(url, param1, param2);
    return secondResponse;
  }
```

This is the Test case I written

```js
it('it  should make make API calls for first and second',async () => {
    sinon.stub(componentSerives, 'fetchApiDetails').resolves(bannerResponse);
});
```

The issue iam facing is., I dont know how to send both first & second APi response in resolves();

on passing it as an array of objects like below., I see firstResponse & secondResponse loading in both objects.

```
[{firstResponse, secondResponse}]
```

can you help me how to stub both the APis and assign it to different responses in destructuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stubbing the wrong thing, according to your own test:

```
it('it  should make make API calls for first and second',async () => {
```

If you are testing `fetchApiDetails` you cannot stub that function out. That makes no sense! Then you would just be testing your own stub.

What you need to stub out or inject, are its dependencies: `_getfirstApiResponse` and `_getSecondApiResponse`. Stub those out simply by having them just resolve some value:

```js
const firstResponse = 42;
const secondResponse  = -42;
sinon.replace(componentSerives, '_getfirstApiResponse', sinon.fake.resolves(firstResponse));
sinon.replace(componentSerives, '_getSecondApiResponse', sinon.fake.resolves(secondResponse  ));

await componentSerives.fetchApiDetails();
assertEquals(componentSerives.formatFirstApiResult, "Result: 42");
assertEquals(componentSerives.formatSecondApiResult, "Result: -42");
```